# How to Create a QT Library Dialog

Tags: c++, qt, dll, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I've just downloaded a copy of QT to evaluate if it will work for a project. My first goal was to create a library that contains a dialog. The goal is to see if QT supports the ability to create modules that can be loaded into various programs. Similar to the way you can create a .dll in Windows and place resources inside.

Is this possible (or reasonable) to do in QT?

If so, how? If not, what options are there for creating reusable QT modules?

Comment: To make things clear: Do you want a Qt-based module to be loaded in the non-Qt application?

Comment: It would be nice if the module could be loaded into a non-Qt application, but that is not required. It could be a Qt module loaded into a Qt application. The module must contain resources (strings, dialogs, images, sound files, ...)  Also, it would be nice if it was platform independent.

Comment: How about build your dll(ex. a.dll) which is QT-based. In your exe, do not link the a.dll, just use LoadDll to invoke the QT dialog you need? But you still need all the QT dlls. If your build a library based on QT,  your exe will be QT-based, because you have to link the QT libs.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is definitely possible to have `Qt` dialogs within a shared library but there are caveats. The biggest issue is that you need to have a full `QApplication` event loop running, which is costly to start and maintain each time you want to call a `Qt`-based dialog, and also means an increased amount of libraries to distribute.

Comment: Do you know how to create a qt app that uses a qt dialog in a library?